# PHPmailer, smtp, mail clients think there are images in the message (but there are none)

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I have a simple phpmailer script to send contact form inquiry via website to my mailbox (gmail - I have also tried few other mail clients to receive it)

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.name.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'username';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->From = $useremail;
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->FromName = $firstname;
$mail->Encoding = "base64";
$mail->Timeout = 200;
$mail->ContentType = "text/html";
$mail->addAddress($email, $name);
$mail->Subject = $mailsubject;  
$mail->Body = "body"
```

For some reason, in all the e-mail clients I've tried, the mail client acts as there are pictures in the message, so it says: for protection we've blocked the images, click here to show images.

Can anyone please tell me what is causing it? as there are no images in the message.

Comment: The html in that body doesn't contain any src, href or url attributes?

Comment: I've used <br> in the body few times, Now I've changed ContentType ="text/html" to ="text" and the mail client doesn't give the warrning. Is there anyway to use some html attributes without causing that image warning?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that base64-encoded elements are probably the cause. You shouldn't use that as a default transfer encoding, unless you're a spammer of course :).

`text` is not a valid MIME type, so don't do that - `text/plain` or `text/html` are good choices, depending on your content.

Try starting with one the of the [PHPMailer examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), then look at what you're doing differntly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the encondig thing out, however I've removed it from the code and it didn't help. I have changed IsSMTP to IsSendmail and by using Sendmail isntead of smtp, the issue doesn't occur. Does this mean that the smtp server I'm using is sending some other stuff making the mail client think there are some images in it?

Comment: It certainly could be doing something strange. You could check by grabbing a copy of the sent message (see `getSentMIMEMessage()`) and comparing it to what arrives. Generally unless you're doing something odd locally, you're better off with `isMail` than `isSendmail`.